# Decrease variable value of all children firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

How can I update a child value of all children in Firebase Cloud Functions? I found other answers using regex and AngularFire, and some updating on a single level (this is 2 levels) but is there any way to quickly decrease all child variables of a certain key? For example:

```
database -
     posts -
       RaNd_0MK3y1-
          variable: x
       RaNd_0MK3y2
          variable: y
```

and decrease all values of `variable` by 1 upon calling the Cloud Function?

Comment: What do Cloud Functions have to do with this? Also: did you try anything yet? There is some pretty decent documentation for how to [access the Firebase Database from Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) or [from Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start), so you should be able to get somewhere.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Cloud Functions are just what I'm doing, they are irrelevant, this is mainly about editing the database from javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done pretty much as described in the docs and not anything surprising. There's no magic here.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().database);

// later inside your function call
const ref = admin.database().ref('database/posts');
ref.once('value').then(snap => {
   snap.forEach(ss => {
      ss.ref.transaction(val => (val||0) + 1);
   });
});
```

But what you probably want to do is write a function that's triggered on updates to the individual items, then update them in a more one-to-one manner. Hard to tell without a use case. Be sure to see [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: No, I'm really just trying to blanket update every value. Thanks for the answer.